# Delay before queue pausing with sidekiq-limit_fetch

Tags: ruby, redis, queue, sidekiq, pause

We are using `sidekiq-limit_fetch` to have dynamic queues, and require to be able to pause them.

The pause feature does work, but there seems to be a delay before the pause is effective.

I created an [issue](https://github.com/brainopia/sidekiq-limit_fetch/issues/81) in the gem on GitHub.

I have a problem with the pause functionality on a dynamic queue.
Here is a project that shows the problem: https://github.com/cedricbirdly/pause-queue

Requirements: a running local redis server

To reproduce:

1. Execute `launch_sidekiq.sh` .
   This is a sidekiq process that processes the queue "dynamicqueue"
2. Execute `ruby pause_and_enqueue_worker.rb`

As far as I understand, nothing should happen in the sidekiq process, as the queue dynamicqueue is set to pause before enqueuing a new job. However, the worker runs.

If you execute `ruby pause_and_enqueue_worker.rb` a second time, it resets the queue to pause and enqueues a new job, which is not performed
→ That is to me the expected behavior.

If you execute `ruby release_queue.rb`, then the queue processing is resumed and the worker is executed → That is to me the expected behavior.

Conclusion:

It seems there is a delay when pausing a queue before the pause is effective. I would expect it to be immediate. Am I wrong in my expectations?

Comment: Please post your code here, and explain with it where the error or issue is exactly in the code. Also elaborate on what effect you want to get from your code.

Comment: I edited the post and copied the issue I opened on github

Comment: By the way I feel the -1 was really harsh. I did link the github issue I opened on the gem since the beginning, which is fully detailed and gives a full reproduction project ....

Comment: In case that comment was intended for me, that's not my downvote.